# What IDE is this? I've seen it a few times, it's very pretty

Tags: macos, ide

The image on this site:
https://www.leapmotion.com/developers
What program is that girl using?

Comment: looks like customized `vim` to me

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) to me.  The three consecutive `end` statements towards the bottom of the code base indicate that it's Ruby, and the split-windows along with context-aware inspections on the right-hand side are strong indicators that this is a JetBrains product.

The JVM indicator at the bottom kind of clinches it - it's been consistently present in every JetBrains IDE I've touched.

Comment: Now, the site on the *left* - I'm not entirely sure what that is, but I would love to work at a place that let me program Ruby in one screen and watch Anime in another.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say the bar on the right reminded me of JetBrains' ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

Since you took the trouble to add a "`osx`" tag to this, you might be wondering how to do this with Xcode.

And in Xcode preferences, is a "Fonts & Colors" tab which looks like this:

[image: Look at the pretty xcode colors]

You can change the color scheme of your Xcode IDE really easily to make it as eye catching (or eye insulting) as you prefer.